# How I can determine the time between dates with php and mysl?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I want to determine how time elapsed between dates, I have different tables where I have initial time for example [2016-05-28] and [13:36:42] and the other time [2016-05-31] and [09:05:18]

I want to know, how i can determine the time elapsed, in this case i will have "Two days with 20 hours"

The language that i am using are PHP, mysql, with any framework and angularjs, also where is the most recommendable side to make it

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity, then get back to us. If you show some methods, we may tell you which is most recommendable.

Comment: @Strawberry Yea i have stored the dates in a different tables on mysql

Comment: Sure seems like a lack of research effort before asking question

Comment: @charlietfl You are wrong, if you search, there are no questions about this topic

Comment: @RodrigoGarcia a search in google for php time difference or mysql time difference would give you a good start point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple PHP code:

```
<?php
$dates = ['2016-05-12 05:33:02','2016-07-17 05:00:12'];
$time_diff = strtotime($dates[0]) - strtotime($dates[1]);
$time_diff<0?$time_diff*=-1:null;

print floor($time_diff/86400) . ' days ' . floor(($time_diff % 86400) / 3600) . ' hours '  . floor(($time_diff % 3600) / 60) . ' minutes';
?>
```

prints: 65 days 23 hours 27 minutes

Comment: You can also use Time(): $start_date = new DateTime('2007-09-01 04:10:58');
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime('2012-09-11 10:25:00'));
echo $since_start->days.' days total '.  $since_start->y.' years . $since_start->m.' months ' .  $since_start->d.' days ' . $since_start->h.' hours ' . $since_start->i.' minutes;

Answer (score 2):

In mylsq You can use TIMEDIFF and  join  for relation

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(table1.datetime1,table2.datetime2) 
from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id= table2.id
```

The result is in second so you can multply for 60 for minutes .. 60 for hour and 24 for day

Answer (score 2):

MySQL:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
  FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-06-20 12:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-05 12:03:30'))/86400) , ' days ' ,
  FLOOR(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2016-06-20 12:00:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-05 12:03:30')) % 86400) /3600) , ' hours ' ,
  'etc...');
```

prints:
927 days 22 hours etc...